# Costs of multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

In python, what is the cost of creating another process - is it sufficiently high that it's not worth it as a way of handling events?

Context of question:  I'm using radio modules to transmit data from sensors to a raspberry pi.  I have a python script running on the pi, catching the data and handling it - putting it in a MySQL database and occasionally triggering other things.

My dilemma is that if I handle everything in a single script there's a risk that some data packet might be ignored, because it's taking too long to run the processing.  I could avoid this by spawning a separate process to handle the event and then die - but if the cost of creating a process is high it might be worth me focusing on more efficient code than creating a process.

Thoughts people?
Edit to add:

- Sensors are pushing data, at intervals of 8 seconds and up
- No buffering easily available
- If processing takes longer longer than the time till the next reading, it would be ignored and lost. (Transmission system
  guarantees delivery - I need to guarantee the pi is in a position to
  receive it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to address two problems at the same time, and it is getting confusing.

1. Polling frequency: here the question is, how fast you need to poll data so that you don't risk losing some
2. Concurrency and i/o locking: what happens if processing takes longer than the frequency interval

The first problem depends entirely on your underlying architecture: are your sensors *push*ing or *poll*ing to your Raspberry? Is any buffering involved? What happens if your polling frequency is faster than the rate of arrival of data?

My recommendation is to enforce the KISS principle and basically write two tools: one that is entirely in charge of **storing data** data as fast as you need; the other that takes care of **doing something with the data**.

For example the storing could be done by a [memcached](http://memcached.org/) instance, or even a simple [shell pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe) if you're at the prototyping level. The second utility that manipulates data then does not have to worry about polling frequency, I/O errors (what if the SQL database errors?), and so on.

As a bonus, de-coupling data retrieval and manipulation allows you to:

- Test more easily (you can store some data as a sample, and then reply it to the manipulation routine to validate behaviour)
- Isolate problems more easily
- Scale much faster (you could have as many "manipulators" as you need)

Comment: -Sensors are pushing, at around 8 second intervals.   
-No buffering easily available   
-If processing takes longer longer than the time till the next reading, it would be ignored and lost.   (Transmission system guarantees delivery - I need to guarantee the pi is in a position to receive it)   

Agree about separating receipt/storage and processing. 
Edit: Line spacing. Edit 2: I give up on line spacing.

Comment: @user2702772 your comment might be useful for other answers - I suggest you add it as an edit to your question

Comment: Accepted as answer, because while Loic does provide a solution, he doesn't address my core problem - cost.

And while this isn't a whole solution, it helps enough to design something that'll work.  I hope.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Spawning new threads cost depends on what you do with them.

In term of memory, make sure your threads aren't loading themselves with everything, threading shares the memory for the whole application so variables keep their scope.

In term of processing, be sure you don't overload your system.
I'm doing something quite similar for work : I'm scanning a folder (where files are put constantly), and I do stuff on every file.

I use my main thread to initialize the application and spawn the child threads.
One child thread is used for logging.
Others child are for the actual work.

My main loop looks like this :

```
#spawn logging thread
while 1:
    for stuff in os.walk('/gw'):
        while threading.active_count() > 200:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        #spawn new worker thread sending the filepath
    time.sleep(1)
```

This basically means that my application won't use more than 201 threads (200 + main thread).

So then it was just playing with the application, using `htop` for monitoring it's resources consumption and limiting the app to a proper max number of threads.